# Removing items from a dataset that have too few mentions

Tags: r, dataset

I am beginning **R** user and I have a question about a problem I encountered:

- Very large dataset (almost 800k rows)
- This dataset lists all contributions to a politicians in the 90s in the US

After some data cleaning, I needed to reduce the list to a more manageable size. Since I am interested in contributors who have donated more than once, I have decided to try to limit the size of the dataset like that.

The dataset is loaded as "cont"

My intention:

1. Map frequencies of mentions:

   ```
   > table(cont$contributor_name) -> FreqCon
   > subset(FreqCon,Freq>4) -> FMI
   ```
2. Insert an extra column as cont[,43] with name "include" that would say TRUE or FALSE for whether I should subset it

   ```
   for(i in 1:dim(FMI)[1]){
   + ifelse(cont[i,11] %in% FMI[,1],cont[i,43] <- TRUE, cont[i,43] <- FALSE) }
   ```
3. Subset the dataset based on `cont$include`

I hope that is all relevant information. I am happy to provide more info if needed!
Also:`cont[,11] = cont$contributor_name`

*THE PROBLEM*: Currently, **R** is working very hard, but does not seem to change anything in the column. I am confused as to what I am doing wrong, since I am not getting any `warnings()` or Errors.

Maybe I am trying to reinvent the wheel so any way of accomplishing what I set out to do would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop. This is the kind of problem that vectorisation is designed to solve.

```
FreqCon <- table(cont$contributor_name)
FMI <- names(FreqCon)[FreqCon > 4]
small_cont <- subset(cont, contributor_name %in% FMI)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're just trying to subset by frequency. If that is the case, something like the following should work:

```
mydf[mydf$V1 %in% names(which(table(mydf$V1) > 1)), ]
#    V1          V2
# 4   s -0.30538839
# 5   e  1.51178117
# 7   s -0.62124058
# 11  e -0.01619026
```

The logic is to just run `table` across the "V1" column ("contributor_name" for your dataset), and then just identify which ones meet your condition (here I've set it to any "V1" that occurs more than once).

There is no need to create another column as an intermediate step.

If this is indeed what you're after, and you have large data, you may want to consider using the `data.table` package:

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(mydf)
> DT[, N := .N, by = "V1"][N > 1]
   V1          V2 N
1:  s -0.30538839 2
2:  e  1.51178117 2
3:  s -0.62124058 2
4:  e -0.01619026 2
```

In the above, `.N` is like `table` for `data.table` and *does* create a new column (in this case, named "N"). The syntax is a bit different from base R, but it should be much more effective for large data.

---

For these examples, `mydf` was defined as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = sample(letters[1:20], 12, replace = TRUE), 
                   V2 = rnorm(12))
#    V1          V2
# 1   f  0.48742905
# 2   h  0.73832471
# 3   l  0.57578135
# 4   s -0.30538839
# 5   e  1.51178117
# 6   r  0.38984324
# 7   s -0.62124058
# 8   n -2.21469989
# 9   m  1.12493092
# 10  b -0.04493361
# 11  e -0.01619026
# 12  d  0.94383621
```